# PostgreSQL 11 REPEATABLE READ Isolation Level

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to understand PostgreSQL isolation level implementation, and can't understand what I'm doing wrong. 
I am using a local PostgreSQL 11, and DBeaver 5.3.4 as my IDE.

Here is the scenario I'm testing:

```
CREATE SCHEMA Test;
CREATE TABLE Test.T1 (Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY, Col2 CHAR(2) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Test.T1 (Col1, Col2) VALUES (1,'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'C');
```

I open 2 concurrent connection windows to the database.
In the first one, I issue the following commands:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
SELECT * FROM Test.T1 WHERE Col1 = 2;
```

I get the expected result: 2-'B'.
Then, in a separate window, I issue the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Test.T1 SET Col2 = 'XX' WHERE Col1 = 2;
```

Now If switch back to the first window, and issue the same SELECT again:

```
SELECT * FROM Test.T1 WHERE Col1 = 2;
```

Since the transaction was started with REPEATABLE READ isolation, I expect to see the result from the data snapshot, and get a repeatable read of 2-'B', but instead, I get the updated value for Col2 = 2-'xx'.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help and have a wonderful weekend!

Comment: Possibly your IDE trying to "manage" transactions and/or connections for you under the hood. See if you can reproduce it with `psql`.

Comment: @NickBarnes Seems like you are correct. Thanks. If you make it an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: I found the problem - Turns out that by default, DBeaver uses the same underlying connection for all editor windows... had to go into global settings for "SQL Editor" and under connection, check "use separate connections for each editor"...

Comment: Happy to help! But now that you've tracked down both the cause and the solution, I'd say you're more qualified to answer this than I am ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @NickBarnes suggestion, I've tracked down the IDE settings and found the problem.
Turns out that by default, DBeaver uses the same underlying connection for all editor windows...

If you need to use separate connections, go to connection or global settings for "SQL Editor", and under connection, check "use separate connections for each editor".
I find this default a weird choice, but at least now I know the cause.

Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Mine showed "open separate connection for each editor" as checked when I...checked. (LOL).  Maybe it's the default now?